# ¿Como hacer focusout con un elemento vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Tengo un select con vue js definido:

```
dacademics:[
            {text:'Persona Natural',value:'PN'},
            {text:'Bachiller',value:'Bach'},
            {text:'Profesional',value:'Prof'},
            {text:'Técnico Especializado',value:'TE'},
            {text:'Técnico Administrativo',value:'TA'},
            {text:'Obrero A',value:'OA'},
            {text:'Obrero B',value:'OB'}],
```

y en la vista lo cargo el select de la siguiente manera.

```
<select v-model="dacademic" class="form-control" style="height: 35.9px;" placeholder="Seleccione" id="sdacademic">
    <option value="" disabled hidden>Seleccione Grado</option>
    <option v-for="gradoac in dacademics" v-bind:value="gradoac.value">
                                @{{ gradoac.text }}
    </option>
</select>
```

tambien tengo una variable monto total:
que es definida de la siguiente manera

```
newContrato:{CONT_intTiempoContrato:'',CONT_varProfesion:'',CONT_varGradoAcademico:'',CONT_douMontoTotal:'',CONT_intArmadas:'',META_intId:'',PERS_varDNI:'',CONT_datInicio:'',CONT_datFin:'',productos:[],personaSeleccionada:''},
```

y en la vista lo llamo así:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="CONT_douMontoTotal">Monto Total</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="CONT_douMontoTotal" type="number" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Ingrese el  total" v-model="newContrato.CONT_douMontoTotal" min="1" max="13800">
</div>
```

lo que necesito hacer es: cuando selecciono por el ejemplo Persona Natural que el valor del monto total se altere a 1000, si selecciono bachiller que se cambie a 2000, etc.
me gustaria saber si se puede hacer algo como

> v-on:focusout.prevent="cambiarMonto()"

o alguna manera para ejecutar esto desde el codigo en vue js, intente solo con js, pero solo cambia un momento ya que el v-model=newContrato.CONT_douMontoTotal:''  esta vacio

Comment: Probaste con un watch sobre gradoac.value?

Comment: @gbianchi podrías darme una mano aun no utilice watch

Answer (score 1):

Prueba agregando un watch en tu export default

La idea es que un watch es una propiedad que esta monitoreando si una variable cambia de valor, y ejecuta un procedimiento cuando ella cambia.

Por lo tanto, podrias hacer algo asi:

```
export default {.....
    watch: {
        gradoac(){
             cambiarMonto();
        }
    }
}
```

La funcion cambiarMonto, no tiene por que estar definida afuera, podrias hacer lo mismo adentro del watch.

Answer (score 0):

Hice algo asi y por ahora funciona:

```
watch:{
        //
        dacademic : function(){

            switch (this.dacademic) {
                case 'PN':
                    this.newContrato.CONT_douMontoTotal='5700';
                    break;
                case 'Bach':
                    this.newContrato.CONT_douMontoTotal='9300';
                    break;
                case 'Prof':
                    this.newContrato.CONT_douMontoTotal='10500';
                    break;
                case 'TE':
                    this.newContrato.CONT_douMontoTotal='7800';
                    break;
                case 'TA':
                    this.newContrato.CONT_douMontoTotal='6900';
                    break;
                case 'OA':
                    this.newContrato.CONT_douMontoTotal='5700';
                    break;
                case 'OB':
                    this.newContrato.CONT_douMontoTotal='5400';
            }
        }
    }
```

y este es el select:

```
<select v-model="dacademic" class="form-control" style="height: 35.9px;" placeholder="Seleccione" id="sdacademic">
    <option value="" disabled hidden>Seleccione Grado</option>
    <option v-for="gradoac in dacademics" v-bind:value="gradoac.value">
                                @{{ gradoac.text }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Gracias @gbianchi

Comment: marca la respuesta como aceptada para ayudar a mantener la buena salud del sitio, gracias :D